# Uninstall Ubuntu from Asus chromebox

Tags: system-installation

I installed Ubuntu with Kodi on an Asus Chromebox but have no sound.

I would like to uninstall Ubuntu and start again, can any body tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Simply create an Ubuntu bootable USB stick (see : [How to create a bootable USB
stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows))

Launch the installation by booting on the USB stick and simply select :

```
Erase Ubuntu 14.04 and reinstall.
```

on the allocate drive space step.

Comment: No problem, keep me updated if you managed to get sound back after re-installation.